# move subview when keyboard show up

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i am trying to show comments list by using subview. I added subview to self.view, and i added a tableview to it in order to show comments list. now i want to enable user to add comment, i tried to add another subview to the first one with text field and button in the bottom of the screen, but now i want to move this view up when the keyboard show up and then back to bottom when submitting the comment, i tried to change commentView frame when textfieldBeginEditing but it do not change !! my way do not work, do you have any idea to do what i want ?

thanks

this is what i am doing, the view called myview is what i want to move up:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

// notification button
myView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth,screenHeight)];
[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[myView setTag:2013];

commentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,screenHeight-70,screenWidth,70)];
[commentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
// [commentView viewWithTag:2031];

table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,50, screenWidth, screenHeight-100)];;
table.dataSource=self;
table.delegate=self;

UILabel *currentdate = [[UILabel alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,screenWidth-40,50)];
currentdate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[currentdate setTextColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
[currentdate setText:@"Comments"];
currentdate.textAlignment= UITextAlignmentCenter;
currentdate.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0];


commentFeild = [[UITextField alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,10,screenWidth-60,30)];

commentFeild.placeholder=@"add comment";
commentFeild.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[commentFeild setTextColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
commentFeild.textAlignment= UITextAlignmentRight;
commentFeild.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
[commentFeild.layer setCornerRadius:14.0f];
[commentFeild setTag:2113];
//[commentFeild setDelegate:self];

UIButton *doneBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
doneBtn.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth-45, 10,40, 30);
doneBtn.backgroundColor = [ UIColor clearColor];
[doneBtn setTitle:@"done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[doneBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[doneBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(hide) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *add=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
add.frame = CGRectMake(5,10,50,30);
add.backgroundColor = [ UIColor clearColor];
[add setTitle:@"add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[add setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[add addTarget:self action:@selector(addComment) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

if(![taskObject.status isEqualToString:@"doneTask"])
{
    [commentView addSubview:commentFeild];
    [commentView addSubview:add];
}

[myView addSubview:doneBtn];
[myView addSubview:currentdate];
[myView addSubview:table];
[myView addSubview:commentView];

[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

Comment: paste your code that doesn't work for you

Comment: If you are providing this view through the table view (uitableviewcell) rather than adding as a subview it will be easy for you. Tableview already takes care of adjusting the frame by adding keyboard listeners. Still if you want to add as subview only, then you need to add scrollview, connect appropriate delegates, and add the comment view to the subview. In the text filed will begin editing, you should set the content offset of the subview accordingly. Hope this helps.

Comment: adding the textfield to the tableview show it in the last row and o want it to be allows shown.

Comment: if the view in question is in a scroll view or table view, you can simply set the scrollView's contentInset to add padding at the bottom enough to avoid the keyboard.

Comment: did u check out the new answer .. ?

Comment: see the edited answer i put 2 methods "viewDidAppear" and "viewDidDisappear"

Comment: check out the new edited answer replay if it is working or not ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i thought u want to move the tableview, hear is the code of yours modified one

```
       @interface ViewController (  <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>
     {
        BOOL KeyboardShown;
     }

     @end

     @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     KeyboardShown = NO;

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
     CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
     CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

// notification button

    UIView *myView,*commentView;

    myView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth,screenHeight)];
    [myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [myView setTag:2013];

   commentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,screenHeight-70,screenWidth,70)];
   [commentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
// [commentView viewWithTag:2031];

    UITableView *table;
    table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,50, screenWidth, screenHeight-100)];;
   table.dataSource=self;
   table.delegate=self;
   table.tag = 12345;

    UILabel *currentdate = [[UILabel alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,screenWidth-40,50)];
    currentdate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [currentdate setTextColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
    [currentdate setText:@"Comments"];
    currentdate.textAlignment= NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    currentdate.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0];


     UITextField *commentFeild = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,10,screenWidth-60,30)];

    commentFeild.placeholder=@"add comment";
    commentFeild.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [commentFeild setTextColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
    commentFeild.textAlignment= NSTextAlignmentRight;
   commentFeild.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
   [commentFeild.layer setCornerRadius:14.0f];
   [commentFeild setTag:2113];
   commentFeild.delegate = self;
    //[commentFeild setDelegate:self];

   UIButton *doneBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   doneBtn.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth-45, 10,40, 30);
   doneBtn.backgroundColor = [ UIColor clearColor];
   [doneBtn setTitle:@"done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [doneBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [doneBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(hide) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   UIButton *add=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   add.frame = CGRectMake(5,10,50,30);
   add.backgroundColor = [ UIColor clearColor];
   [add setTitle:@"add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [add setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [add addTarget:self action:@selector(addComment)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


     //    if(![taskObject.status isEqualToString:@"doneTask"])
     //    {
     //        [commentView addSubview:commentFeild];
     //        [commentView addSubview:add];
     //    }

[myView addSubview:doneBtn];
[myView addSubview:currentdate];
[myView addSubview:table];
[myView addSubview:commentView];
[commentView addSubview:commentFeild];
[self.view addSubview:myView];

}

  - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self  selector:@selector(keyboardDidDisappear:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
  }

  - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
   {
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
   }





 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
      [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
      return 1;
    }
   -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
       return 5;
    }

     -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
       {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

       cell.textLabel.text = @"hello";
       return cell;


   }

    - (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
     {
        //UIView *containerView = [self.view viewWithTag:2013]; comment this and get tableview by TAG
       UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:12345];
       UIView *commentView = [self.view viewWithTag:1000];//i changed the tag and see u missed the tag for this view in viewDisLoad method check it once


     if(!KeyboardShown)
     {
        KeyboardShown = YES;
         NSLog(@"KeyBoard appeared");
        NSDictionary *info=[notification userInfo];
        NSValue *aValue=[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

        CGRect keyBoardRect=[aValue CGRectValue];
        keyBoardRect=[self.view convertRect:keyBoardRect fromView:nil];
        CGFloat keyBoardTop=keyBoardRect.origin.y; //i am getting the height of the keyboard


        CGRect commentViewRect = commentView.frame;
         commentViewRect.origin.y = keyBoardTop - 70; //it is the height of comment view

        CGRect tableRect = tableView.frame;
        tableRect.size.height = tableRect.size.height - keyBoardTop + 77;//adjust the height



       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
       tableView.frame = tableRect;
       commentView.frame = commentViewRect;

   }];



   }


 }




    - (void)keyboardDidDisappear:(NSNotification *)notification
    {

     // UIView *containerView = [self.view viewWithTag:2013]; //comment this
     //dong same as above , ressetting the same as above
     CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
     CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
     CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:12345];
    UIView *commentView = [self.view viewWithTag:1000];

    if(KeyboardShown)
    {
       KeyboardShown = NO;
       CGRect tableRect =CGRectMake(0,50, screenWidth, screenHeight-100);
       CGRect commentViewRect = CGRectMake(0,screenHeight-70,screenWidth,70);


        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        tableView.frame = tableRect;
        commentView.frame = commentViewRect;

      }];
    }
   }









 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
   {
      [textField resignFirstResponder];
      return YES;
   }

@end
```

Comment: isn't beginAnimations: deprecated? I think +[UIView animateWithDuration:...] is preferred.

Comment: i am doing the show of my view when the user do an action, so i will but the code in the [viewDidLoad] in that action, shall i put the notification too ?

Comment: u mean u are showing the "myView"  when user did some action rite, ya u can put it in "-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated" method and better remove those observers once in "- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated" method. i will update my code about this

Comment: i have it done, but when the keyboard show up all the view scroll up, i want just the table view to scroll and the section having "title" to stay , that why i divided myview to more than one section

Comment: i want to ask you something else, when the keyboard return it returns so slowly, the previous view shows for a second before the keyboard returns, why?

Comment: ya change the duration wait i am checking ur code i will update once i did ok

Comment: check out the new edited answer replay if it is working or not

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40109/discussion-between-shan-and-etab)

Comment: come to chat if u hav any problem

Comment: are u there one thing replace the "UIKeyboardDidHideNotification" with "UIKeyboardWillHideNotification" this will eliminate the delay in the animation hope u get this :)

Answer (score 2):

U need to use notifications when keyboard appeared and disappeared

in `viewDidLoad` method add this

```
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidDisappear:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

above methods get fired when keyboard appeared and disappeared use this to make adjustments of ur tableview

for exaple

```
  -(void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
  {
      NSLog(@"KeyBoard appeared");
      NSDictionary *info=[notification userInfo];
      NSValue *aValue=[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

      CGRect keyBoardRect=[aValue CGRectValue];
      keyBoardRect=[self.view convertRect:keyBoardRect fromView:nil];
      CGFloat keyBoardTop=keyBoardRect.origin.y; //i am getting the height of the keyboard

      self.aTableView.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyBoardTop+50, 0); //adjust the height by setting the "contentInset"


  }
```

when keyboard disappeared do like this

```
  -(void)keyboardDidDisappear:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
       NSLog(@"KeyBoard Disappeared");

       [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
       self.addContactTableView.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, 0); //set to normal by setting the "contentInset" 

       [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
```

a little work around this u may achieve your requirement

hope this helps u :)

Comment: i want to move the hole view that contains the table view, not the table view itself.

Comment: ok then then change the frame of that view when u got notification

Comment: i updated my question, did you notice ? i can not get it work

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go through the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

Comment: huh? should things just happen?